# how to use Widgets with NSNotificationCenter in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios7, widget, nsnotifications, ios-app-extension

I want to create a widget by using `NSNotificationCenter`  in ios8  is that possible?
how to use the `NSNotificationCenter` in **Widgets**. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Chenna :) Mixing the notification center that's part of the user interface in iOS (or OS X) and `NSNotificationCenter` is a common mistake when working with Cocoa. The `NSNotificationCenter` class is responsible for notifying your classes on various events which you can assign using the `addObserver` or `addObserverForName` methods (you can read more in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003701)).

If you want to create Widgets for the Notification Center that is part of the user interface in iOS 8 you should read the article about [Extensions in the Today view](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1) (AKA widgets) in the App Extension Programming Guide :)

Comment: Widgets are extensions, they work outside of your app and therefore they aren't made only by code in your app, you need to edit your app's Info.plist file. The article i linked to (Extensions in the Today view) explains this well :)

Comment: i want to create a widget like hello world. how to create that one

Comment: @haag so is not possible to use [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] or is possible in a different way?

Comment: [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] is responsible for another kind of notifications, it has nothing to do with notifications in the user interface in iOS. read the articles i linked to if you want to learn more :)